# Kaazing Clustering Information

Tags: jms, kaazing

Trying to create the kaazing jms clustering on localhost with two cluster member,

Reference URL : https://developer.kaazing.com/documentation/jms/3.1/howto-admin-ha.html#ha_cluster

1. Do i have to install two separate versions of kaazing jms on my machine having two separate gateway-config.xml file, as currently using gateway-config.xml default file shipped with kaazing JMS edition.
2. How can i simulate 100 websocket connections using javascript jmsclient.js for load testing for clustering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create separate cluster configuration files in same kaazing instance, that means no need to install new instance. For configuration see below link

http://developer.kaazing.com/documentation/jms/4.0/high-availability/u_ha.html#demo